# JUnit + Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring, junit, apache-camel

Suppose I have these two routes

```
<camelContext> 
    <route>
        <from ref="incoming" />
        <!-- some processors -->
        <inOnly ref="outgoing" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from ref="outgoing" />
        <!-- some processors -->
        <inOnly ref="finish" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

In the real context they are JMS queues which is fine. But I want to test that the routing is correct so I changed JMS components in the testContext.xml to:

```
incoming -> direct
outgoing -> mock
finish -> mock
```

I want those inOnly queues to be mocks so I can test them for the number of messages. The problem is that a mock queue cannot work as an input queue in the second route. How can I fix this?

Comment: Feels less like a JUnit test and more like an integration test to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579358/testing-camel-with-mockendpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually [embedd](http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code.html) an ActiveMQ broker when doing automated integration JUnit tests with Camel and JMS.

I would also consider a simpler scenario where you have "outgoing" as a [seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) endpoint. Then you would only have to check the "finish" mock endpoint for messages, and you know the entire route works. For more complicated routing scenarios, it takes a bit of thinking to cover it in JUnit tests, if you should do it at all.

Comment: It's not an integration test. I just want to check messages in two places - between the routes and at the end. But using `mock:outgoing` does not work (for some reason it can't be in the `<from>`)...

Comment: Okay, you really want to mock the middle one as well. That is actually described in code and text here: http://camel.apache.org/mock.html#Mock-Mockingexistingendpoints

Using the "adviceWith" concept. I think that is describe except for direct instead of JMS queues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stub component instead of JMS etc. Its the seda/vm queues under the hood, so you can send and consume messages from it
http://camel.apache.org/stub